# How do we call .name() method of an enum from spring xml?

Tags: java, spring

I hava an enum in java

```
package a.b.c;
enum ABC{
  HELLO,
  HI
}
```

And I have an xml reference that has object of this enum

```
<bean name="a.b.c.ABC" ref="someClass" method="someMethod" injectable="true"/>
```

Now I want to pass the value of this enum to another remote method. So I need to call `.name()` or `toString()` of this value . Can I do that directly via some xml reference?

Comment: `toString()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString()

Comment: I wanted a way to call this method directly via xml.

Comment: you only know the method signature